# How to do dynamic update in hibernate?

Tags: hibernate

By default dynamic update is not turned on. I would like to update some of the fields, without loading entire record. In hibernate-annotations 3.5.6 Final (which is latest), no support for @DynamicUpdate. Is there any alternate way to update partially without loading entire record or writing the query.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by using hibernate-core 4.1.7.Final